# Can I use content negotiation to conditionally serve SVG?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, firefox, google-chrome, svg

In theory I should be able to see if a browser supports SVG by looking at the `accept` header, but as far as I can tell no modern browser accurately reports `image/svg+xml`. **Has anyone successfully implemented conditionally serving SVG using content negotiation?** It feels like a bit of a mirage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers are trying to minimise the size of the http headers they send as they contribute overhead to every request. There are other better ways to figure out if a browser supports SVG e.g. [modernizer](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/)

Comment: That'll be a no then :) I'm actually using modernizr, but really like the idea of only serving content once. Oh well, pity, because I'm of the opinion content negotiation should be more highly leveraged - especially for feature detection like this. Thanks.